# How do I replace parts of a formatted date with another value in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: date, replace, libreoffice-calc

I am using Libreoffiec 7.5 (currently the newest version) on Ubuntu 22.04.

I have a lot of cells with date values formatted with the German locale (if this matters), like

```
1.4.2023
4.4.2023
```

etc.

I want to replace the month, or the year, in all these cells with a different (valid) number. How do I do this? Plain search & replace does not work probably because it scans the actual value, which is a number, not the formatted date. Preferably without having to calculate beforehand how many days, or seconds, or whatever I would have to add to the date to end up with a shift of N years or months.

**Plan B if the above is not possible**: How do I tell Libreoffice quickly (by hotkey?) that it should autofill a *specific* year into cells which receive a date without year, so that when I type `1.4.` (April 1st) it doesn't autofill the *current* year, but my previously specified year into the date? This should persist at least until closing LibreOffice, or until setting another year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer** to both questions is **No way**.

**More details:** regardless of the formatting of the cell with the date, the [Find & Replace](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/02100000.html) operation will not perform the required operation (you are right, this is due to the internal representation of the date as the number of days counted from the "base date", [Tools - Options - LibreOffice Calc - Calculate - Date section](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/optionen/01060500.html)); entering an incomplete date (*day.month*) always refers to the current year.

**Full answer**.

*General recommendation for converting existing data: always convert in two stages - create an auxiliary range in which, using formulas or built-in Calc mechanisms, create the necessary data, after carefully checking the correctness of the conversion, use Copy and Paste Special - Values in place of the original data and clear auxiliary range.*

Let's assume that the dates you showed in your question as an example are in column A.

Use the [Year()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_year.html), [Month()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_month.html), and [Day()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_day.html) functions to get the corresponding parts of the original date, use the [DATE()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_date.html) function to generate a new date with the necessary corrections.

For example, to get a date one and a half years after the original, you can use the formula

`=DATE(YEAR(A2);MONTH(A2)+18;DAY(A2))`
or

`=DATE(YEAR(A2)+1;MONTH(A2)+6;DAY(A2))`

Of course, instead of any of the parameters of the DATE() function, you can substitute a fixed value. For example, `=DATE(1827;MONTH(A2);DAY(A2))` will return with the day and month from cell A2, but for 1827 (So you can implement the **Plan B** you described).

In addition to the four functions described here, Calc contains a rather large set of functions for working with dates. You can see them in the Date section of the [Function Wizard](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060000.html):

[image: Wizard]

or you can read a detailed description of each of these functions in the [corresponding **Help** section](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060102.html?DbPAR=CALC)

[image: Help]

Comment: I was afraid the answer would go that way, but thank you very much for explaining in detail. It makes sense ...

Comment: After considering a little more what my use case was, I ended up creating a list of "delta days" which I can now copy, and "Paste special" with substraction, to shift dates by specific years and months. This is cumbersome, but it works. Thank you again!